# How to show feature image, Title, Breadcrumb before Page in flatsome theme

Tags: page-template

[image]

I can find how to display it in Post and Product section, but in Page I don't see it anywhere

So please guide me how to display Featured Image, Title and Breadcrumb behind the header like the picture I have attached - theme flatsome. Thank you

Comment: Third party themes and plugins are off topic here. Questions about theme specific functionality are best directed to the theme's author or support resources.

Comment: You should create a child theme and then replace the page template for the child theme with your customized version.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.